# How to determine if a string object is a integer, double, boolean, date, or string using python?

Tags: python, string, object, types

I'd like a function that can determine if a certain input falls into one of the following categories

- integer
- double
- boolean
- date
- string

This is the function I currently have, but the challenge is that if the input comes as a string, I'd like the function to still determine if it's a date, integer, double, boolean, or string

```
def text_type_determine(i):
    if type(i) == int:
        return 'integer'
    elif type(i) == float:
        return 'double'
    elif type(i) == bool:
        return 'boolean'
    elif type(i) == str:
        return 'string'
```

For example, I'd like the following inputs to yield the associated results:

- '2015-01-01' -> 'date'
- '1' -> 'integer'
- '1.0' -> 'double'
- 'true' -> 'boolean'
- 'random string' -> string

Comment: Do you have the beginning of an idea how to do this yourself? This site tends to frown on simple "give me some code" questions even if they're asked politely.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` like this:

```
def text_type_determine(i):
    i = eval(i)
    if type(i) == int:
        return 'integer'
    elif type(i) == float:
        return 'double'
    elif type(i) == bool:
        return 'boolean'
    elif type(i) == str:
        return 'string'
```

So this:

```
print(text_type_determine("12.3"))
```

Would output:

```
double
```

Comment: Coming as a string is a *second* alternative, not the only one.  `i` might be `4.5`, in which case you'd get an error on that `eval(i)` line.

Comment: Just edit so if it is string it evals, else it check type()

Answer (score 0):

You can test the conversion with a try/catch instruction as (**only for int**):

```
def isInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
     except ValueError:
        return False

def text_type_determine(s):
    if isInt(s):
        return 'integer'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cast each item to the various types in logical succession and handle every case:

```
from datetime import datetime

def text_type_determine(i):
    # datetime is the most specific, so start with it
    try:
        datetime.strftime(i, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return 'date'
    except:
        # Next try int before float since float(`4`) will work
        try:
            int(i)
            return 'integer'
        except:
            try:
                # Python uses float not double, but I think it should do
                float(i)
                return 'double'
            except:
                pass
    # Finally if all our number cases fail, check if
    # we have a boolean, otherwise it's just a string
    if i in ['true', 'false']:
        return 'boolean'
    return 'string'
```

This of course assumes that dates are only of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and that all booleans will be either `true` or `false`. It should be pretty straight forward to add in more options.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by date as it does not appear in your own code, but if you want to evaluate potential ints, floats which are strings etc.. you can use  `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

def text_type_determine(i):
    types = {int: 'integer', float: 'double', bool: 'boolean', str: 'string'}
    try:
        return types.get(type(literal_eval(i)))
    except ValueError:
        return types.get(type(i))
```

If you wanted to test if the object could be parsed as a date you could use [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) in something like:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

def text_type_determine(i):
    types = {int: 'integer', float: 'double', bool: 'boolean', str: 'string', datetime: "date"}
    for tpe in [literal_eval, parser.parse]:
        try:
            return types.get(type(tpe(i)))
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            pass
    return types.get(type(i))
```

Which will give you:

```
In [17]: text_type_determine(1)
Out[17]: 'integer'

In [18]: text_type_determine(datetime.now())
Out[18]: 'date'

In [19]: text_type_determine("2016-03-19")
Out[19]: 'date'

In [20]: text_type_determine("2016")
Out[20]: 'integer'

In [21]: text_type_determine("2016.23")
Out[21]: 'double'
```

You might want to rearrange the checking order as `dateutil.parser` could give you some unexpected output. If your dates are always in the same order then just use `datetime.strptime` to do the parsing, if not bar trying every possible date variation with strptime then dateutil will be a much better solution.